# Avoid "require" repeating in Router files

Tags: node.js, express

This is a part of Main Server File in Nodejs

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

//Module for  User Login , Logout, Session 
var objUserModule = require('./node_scripts/UserModule');
app.use('/', objUserModule);
```

and in UserModule

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var router = express.Router();

//LOGOUT USER
router.get('/LogOut', function(req, res) {});
```

Is there any way to avoid the **require statements in beginning of all router files**  (avoid including those modules individually in each routers)

i m new to Nodejs and so i believe there is a better way to do this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in `Router` to the module. That way you don't have to require it again.

**Main**

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

//Module for  User Login , Logout, Session 
var objUserModule = require('./node_scripts/UserModule')(express.Router());
app.use('/', objUserModule);
```

**UserModule**

```
module.exports = function(router) {

  //LOGOUT USER
  router.get('/LogOut', function(req, res) {});

  return router;
};
```

Comment: Thank You .... Finally Code is like
var objUserModule = require('./node_scripts/UserModule')(router,request);
app.use('/', objUserModule);